# How can I get the "id" value with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, key

How can I get the `id` value from the following HTML?

```
print(type(author_info))
output: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>



print(author_info)
output: <script data-mru-fragment="models/user/journal" type="text/plain">
    {
        "name": "on-line журнал РАЗНЫЕ ЛЮДИ",
        "id": "-2812448",
        "auId": "8911662942803793376",
        "email": "rl_journal",
        "dir": "/community/rl_journal/",
    


    "isVip": false,
    "isCommunity": true,
    "isVideoChannel": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are seeing is in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format, you can convert it to a Python dictionary (`dict`) using the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, and then access the `id` key:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

script_doc = """
<script data-mru-fragment="models/user/journal" type="text/plain">
    {
        "name": "on-line журнал РАЗНЫЕ ЛЮДИ",
        "id": "-2812448",
        "auId": "8911662942803793376",
        "email": "rl_journal",
        "dir": "/community/rl_journal/",
        "isVip": false,
        "isCommunity": true,
        "isVideoChannel": false
}</script>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(script_doc, "html.parser")

json_data = json.loads(soup.find("script").string)
# With your example using `author_info`:
# json_data = json.loads(author_info.string)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(type(json_data))
<class 'dict'>

>>> print(json_data["id"])
-2812448
```